# Stackoverflow EditText Widget

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

The error has to do with me calling the setText() method and that invoking the TextWatcher recursively.  To fix this I am trying the remove the watcher and add it again after I set the text.  I need the TextWatcher active in order for my EditText error to work or the mPassword edittext.  If I use the following code to remove and add the TextWatcher:

```
mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
phone = mPassword.getText().toString();
phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
mPassword.setText(phone);
flag = false;
mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
```

It still crashes on me.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mUsername;

private EditText mPassword;
Editable s;

private Drawable error_indicator;

String phone;
private boolean flag = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting custom drawable instead of red error indicator,
    //error_indicator = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    int left = 0;
    int top = 0;

    //int right = error_indicator.getIntrinsicHeight();
    //int bottom = error_indicator.getIntrinsicWidth();

    phone = "";

    mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    // Called when user type in EditText
    mUsername.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mUsername));
    mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
}

private class InputValidator implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText et;

    private InputValidator(EditText editText) {
        this.et = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onTextChanged() Method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (s.length() != 0 && flag) {
            switch (et.getId()) {
            case R.id.etUsername: {
                if (!Pattern.matches("(^[A-Za-z][\\w-(.|\\n)]+@[A-Za-z][\\w-(.|\\n)]+(.|\\n)(com|net|org|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|in|aero|jobs|museum))$", s )) {
                    et.setError("please enter a valid email address");
                }
            }
            break;

            case R.id.etPassword: {
                //doWork();

                phone = mPassword.getText().toString();
                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);

                if (!Pattern.matches("\\([1-9]\\d{2}\\)[0-9]{3}-\\d{4}$", s)) {
                    et.setError("please enter a valid 10 digit phone number");
                }

                mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
                phone = mPassword.getText().toString();
                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
                mPassword.setText(phone);
                flag = false;
                mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));

                break;
            }
            }
        }
        else {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}

public String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    final StringBuffer sbPhone = new StringBuffer(phoneNumber);

    if (sbPhone.length() == 9) {
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("-") == -1) {
            sbPhone.insert(8, "-");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In formatPhoneNumber() Method - 9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (sbPhone.length() == 8) {
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("-") != -1) {
            sbPhone.delete(sbPhone.indexOf("-"), sbPhone.indexOf("-"));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In formatPhoneNumber() Method - 8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (sbPhone.length() == 5) {
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("(") != -1) {
            sbPhone.delete(sbPhone.indexOf("("), sbPhone.indexOf("(")+1);
        }
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("(") != -1) {
            sbPhone.delete(sbPhone.indexOf(")"), sbPhone.indexOf(")"));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In formatPhoneNumber() Method - 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (sbPhone.length() == 3) {
        if (sbPhone.indexOf("(") == -1) {
            sbPhone.insert(0, "(");
        }
        if (sbPhone.indexOf(")") == -1 && sbPhone.indexOf("(") != -1) {
            sbPhone.append(")");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In formatPhoneNumber() Method - 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return sbPhone.toString();
}
}
```

The error:

```
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:324)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:174)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:7106)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6955)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7551)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4410)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8430)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4413)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:108)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity.formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at com.example.edittexttest.MainActivity$InputValidator.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 11:59:51.910: E/AndroidRuntime(24049):    at android.widget.TextView.se
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which is this line ? `formatPhoneNumber(MainActivity.java:187)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two different objects of listener while removing or adding.

```
mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
                phone = mPassword.getText().toString();
                phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
                Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
                mPassword.setText(phone);
                flag = false;
                mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));
```

This must be

Add members as

```
private InputValidator mPasswordTextWatcher = null;
private InputValidator mUserNameTextWatcher = null;
```

in `onCreate()`

```
mPasswordTextWatcher = new InputValidator(mPassword);
mUserNameTextWatcher = new InputValidator(mUsername);

// Called when user type in EditText
mUsername.addTextChangedListener(mUserNameTextWatcher);
mPassword.addTextChangedListener(mPasswordTextWatcher);
```

and do it now as

```
mPassword.removeTextChangedListener(mPasswordTextWatcher);
phone = mPassword.getText().toString();
phone = formatPhoneNumber(phone);
Log.i("PHONE", "Phone NUMB IS:"+phone);
mPassword.setText(phone);
flag = false;
mPassword.addTextChangedListener(mPasswordTextWatcher);
```

Do same for username EditText.

Comment: It still crashes on me when I do this.